# Translating Access SQL Statement to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, if-statement, translate

I have the following code, which i generated using Access DB, i need to translate it to
T-SQL, am mainly getting error on the IIF statement

```
SELECT dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
Sum(IIf([gender]='Male' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage],1,0)) AS Male, 
Sum(IIf([gender]='Female' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage],1,0)) AS Female

 FROM dbo.casyAgeGroups, [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails]
GROUP BY dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, 
         dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
         [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType
HAVING ((([qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType)=0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use CASE instead of IIF. And change HAVING to WHERE statement.

```
SELECT dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
Sum(CASE 
       WHEN ([gender]='Male' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male, 
Sum(CASE 
       WHEN ([gender]='Female' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female

 FROM dbo.casyAgeGroups, [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails]
 WHERE  ((([qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType)=0))
 GROUP BY dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, 
         dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
         [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType
```

Also as soon as you use HAVING condition `EntityType=0` you don't need to group by this field:

```
SELECT dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
Sum(CASE 
       WHEN ([gender]='Male' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male, 
Sum(CASE 
       WHEN ([gender]='Female' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female

 FROM dbo.casyAgeGroups, [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails]
 WHERE  ((([qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType)=0))
 GROUP BY dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, 
         dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a [CASE statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Something like

```
SELECT  dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, 
        dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
        Sum(CASE WHEN [gender]='Male' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male, 
        Sum(CASE WHEN [gender]='Female' And [age]>=[startage] And [age]<=[endage] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Female
FROM    dbo.casyAgeGroups, 
        [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails]
GROUP BY    dbo.casyAgeGroups.Sequence, 
            dbo.casyAgeGroups.Description, 
            [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType
HAVING  [qryStats-AgeGenderProfileDetails].EntityType=0
```